# How to add a character to specific index in string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update, where-clause

I have a db with email-addresses which are 15 characters in total.

Some are 14 characters long and they have the same in common, they miss a `0` in their name at the 3th index.

I had a what similar problem with the id numbers but that was easy to fix because i had to push 0 to the first index.

My expected results should be changing `'aa-001@test.me'` to `'aa-0001@test.me'`.

Comment: How about the straightforward approach - `CONCAT(SUBSTR(...,1,3),'0',SUBSTR(...,3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a `0` as 4th character in `email`s having 14 characters, you may simply use `SUBSTR` :

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(email, 1, 3), '0', SUBSTR(email, 4))
FROM mytable
WHERE LENGTH(email) = 14
```

Another solution is to use `REGEXP_REPLACE`, with a regular expression that matches only on emails with 14 characters ; this avoids the need for a `WHERE` clause, as emails that do not match the pattern will be returned untouched :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '^(.{3})(.{11})$', CONCAT('$1', '0', '$2'))
FROM t
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5aadb86c2c45b45d3900bfa9969dafca)* :

```
 WITH t AS (SELECT 'aa-001@test.me' email UNION SELECT 'bb-0002@test.me')
 SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(email, 1, 3), '0', SUBSTR(email, 4))
 FROM t
 WHERE LENGTH(email) = 14

| CONCAT(SUBSTR(email, 1, 3), '0', SUBSTR(email, 4)) |
| :----------------------------------------------------- |
| aa-0001@test.me                                        |


 WITH t AS (SELECT 'aa-001@test.me' email UNION SELECT 'bb-0002@test.me')
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '^(.{3})(.{11})$', CONCAT('$1', '0', '$2'))
 FROM t

| REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '^(.{3})(.{11})$', CONCAT('$1', '0', '$2')) |
| :---------------------------------------------------------------- |
| aa-0001@test.me                                                   |
| bb-0002@test.me
```